# AdMob Interstitial after five GameOver

Tags: java, admob

I can not implement my Interstitial after five gameover. I found the way to implement it at the beginning but i want it to show after our every five deaths.
I worked on my MainActivity i havent game over class but the game over details are in my Game Panel someone has any advice, can you help me? thank you in advance.
I here the screen of my Interstial.

```
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //turn title off
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "");

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {


        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.

            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this,
                    new GameActivity().getClass());
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

}
```

}

Comment: Hi @Ufo, and welcome to StackOverflow! Since this is your first question, here are some hints you can use to either revise it or ask new questions; [How do I ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) In particular, you may want to consider [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that your question contains as little irrelevant code as possible; this proves that you've done what you could to isolate the problem, and it increases the chance that someone will like to answer. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a counter to represent the amount of deaths and present the ad after that condition is met.

Once condition is met:

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
    mInterstitialAd.show();
}
```

Comment: can you show me the writing code in order to increase the interstitial with the gameover? help me